# Is there a configuration setting for how many pages ANALYZE will scan?

Tags: postgresql, configuration

Is there a setting that controls how many records/pages are scanned by the PostgreSQL `ANALYZE` command? It looks like by default it scans 30,000 pages and 30,000 records. The [PostgreSQL Server Configuration Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config.html) lists tons of options, but I don't see anything specific to `ANALYZE`.

Comment: The statistics targets affect what `ANALYZE` does - both the `default_statistics_target` and per-column stats settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each column of a table has an `attstattarget` property (stored in [`pg_attribute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-attribute.html)) that tells how much data should be stored for it from the statistical sample gathered by `ANALYZE`.

It defaults to [`default_statistics_target`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-OTHER), which itself defaults to `100`.

In [Statistics Used by the Planner](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/planner-stats.html), the doc says:

> The amount of information stored in pg_statistic by ANALYZE, in
>   particular the maximum number of entries in the most_common_vals and
>   histogram_bounds arrays for each column, can be set on a
>   column-by-column basis using the ALTER TABLE SET STATISTICS command,
>   or globally by setting the default_statistics_target configuration
>   variable

The reason behind the `30,000` pages and rows is that the sample size in rows considered by ANALYZE is `300` times the maximum value of `attstattarget` for the sampled table, which would be the default `100`.

The `300` comes from a statistical formula mentioned in the source code
`src/backend/commands/analyze.c`:

```
    /*--------------------
     * The following choice of minrows is based on the paper
     * "Random sampling for histogram construction: how much is enough?"
     * by Surajit Chaudhuri, Rajeev Motwani and Vivek Narasayya, in
     * Proceedings of ACM SIGMOD International Conference on Management
     * of Data, 1998, Pages 436-447.  Their Corollary 1 to Theorem 5
     * says that for table size n, histogram size k, maximum relative
     * error in bin size f, and error probability gamma, the minimum
     * random sample size is
     *      r = 4 * k * ln(2*n/gamma) / f^2
     * Taking f = 0.5, gamma = 0.01, n = 10^6 rows, we obtain
     *      r = 305.82 * k
     * Note that because of the log function, the dependence on n is
     * quite weak; even at n = 10^12, a 300*k sample gives <= 0.66
     * bin size error with probability 0.99.  So there's no real need to
     * scale for n, which is a good thing because we don't necessarily
     * know it at this point.
     *--------------------
     */
    stats->minrows = 300 * attr->attstattarget;
```

As for the number of pages, since rows don't span across pages, at most `N` pages are going to be read to get `N` rows. I believe that `ANALYZE` intentionally aims at fetching this maximum of pages to get the best sample. It makes sense since rows stored in a same page are more likely to be correlated.

Comment: That's some very helpful information and a great write up. Thank you.